# How to eleminate duplicate values in a single file using hadoop mapreduce program

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce

How to eleminate duplicate values in a single file using hadoop mapreduce program
While in output i need unique values
 
For Example: in a file

line 1: Hi this is Ashok

Line 2: Basics of hadoop framework

line 3: Hi this is Ashok

From this example need output only unique values i.e. It should print Line 1 and 3... How to do it....

Answer (score 8):

**This is word count without the count.**

The typical way to do this is to group by the entire line, then only output the key in the reducer. Here is some pseudocode:

```
map(key, value):
   emit (value, null)

reducer(key, iterator):
   emit (key, null)
```

Notice that I'm just outputting value here as the key from the mapper. The value can be null (i.e., `NullWriteable`, or you can just use an integer or whatever.).

In the reducer, I don't care how many I saw, I just output the key.

Comment: I dont need any count... In output it should print unique values in a file... No need of duplicate values...

Comment: i know... that's the point. "This is word count WITHOUT the count." think about it

Comment: It should be possible to use the reducer as combiner for optimization.

Comment: As Praveen Sripati has mentioned, a combiner would call in for optimization. Why is there a hesitation to accept the answer? Ashok, does this not solve your problem?